# Telerik .tssp not getting applied

Tags: telerik, scsf, radgridview

The theme package .tssp created locally it not getting applied for a radgridview.Please help

```
ThemeResolutionService.LoadPackageFile(@"C:\LeNin\My Document\\xyz.tssp");
        ThemeResolutionService.ApplicationThemeName = "xyz";
```

Answer (score 0):

I work for Telerik. I just tested out your question locally using the tssp version of the Desert theme and was successfully able to theme the application and RadGridView using your provided code. If you continue to experience the problem, I recommend submitting a support ticket through Telerik's website. You can do so here:

http://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets.aspx